# Scapy with Python to save packets in a log file with time stamp

Tags: python, logging, scapy

I am using the Scapy library with Pyhton to collect data such as mac address. I am creating a log file that saves the data collected and timestamps it. I would like to save the packet as well, just in case I will need any of the data at a later case.

I've been using some of their methods that displays the packet(show), hexdump and so on, but it only displays the packet, it does not save it in the log file.

Here is a snapshot of my code:

```
mac = p.addr2
        channel = p.fields["Channel"]
        signal = p.fields["dBm_AntSignal"]
        ap = p.addr1
        s_id=p.SC
        packet=hexdump(p)
        logger.log(
            mac=mac,
            signal=signal,
            channel = channel,
            pi=pi_id,
            ap=ap,
            s_id=s_id,
            packet=packet,
    )
```

Comment: can you use wrpcap to write the packets to a file instead of logger?

Comment: yes, I can, but what I want is to have for each set of information the corresponding packet.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it:

```
pac=p.show
```

And then in logger:

```
logger.log(
        mac=mac,
        signal=signal,
        channel = channel,
        pi=pi_id,
        ap=ap,
        s_id=s_id,
        packet=packet,
)
```

Thanks